# Stuck between mysqli procedural and prepare statement

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, prepared-statement

i stated my project using php mysqli procedural, then i decide to prepare and bind the data. Am creating a role based user system. Below is my registration code with the help of @chris85.

```
    <?php

    session_start(); 
    if(is_file('include/connection.php'))
    include_once('include/connection.php');
    else
    exit('Database FILES MISSING:(');


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $errors = array();
       $data = array();
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
        $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirm_password'];  
       $created_at = $_POST['created_at'];
        $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);    

      $created_at = date('Y-m-d');
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, user_name, user_type, email, password, created_at) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $name, $last_name, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password_hash, $created_at)){
         echo "Binding paramaters failed:(" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
         echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
        }

        if($stmt) {
            $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully registered, login here!";
            header('Location: index.php');

        }
        else{
            echo "Registration failed";
        }

    }

    $mysqli->close();

    ?>
                <?php 

            //check for any errors
    //              if(isset($error)){
    //                  foreach($error as $error){
    //                      echo '<p style="color: red">'.$error.'</p>';
    //                  }
    //              }
              ?>

      <form name="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo ($name) ?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value='<?php echo ($last_name) ?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value='<?php echo ($user_name) ?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Type</td>
          <td>
          <select name="user_type" required>
            <option value="member">Member</option>
            <option value="leader">Leader</option>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td><input type="email" name="email" value='<?php echo ($email) ?>'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
          <td><a href='index.php'>Login</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>   
    </div>
    <script>
    // function check(){
    //  if(document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('confirm_password').value ){
    //      alert('password not match');
    //      return false;
    //  }else{
    //      return true;
    //  }
    // }
    </script>
    <?php
    if(is_file('include/footer.php'))
    include_once('include/footer.php');
    ?>
```

So, now am trying to do the same my login system inluding stmt and bind. Have kinder got stuck on how to execute the role part. below is my login code.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
         header('Location: profile.php');
    }

    session_start(); 
    if(is_file('include/connection.php'))
        include_once('include/connection.php');
    else
        exit('Database FILES MISSING:(');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password' AND user_type = '$user_type'"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $user_type)){
            echo "Bind failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ")" . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);             
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = strtoupper($row['name']);
            $user_type = strtolower($row['user_type']);
            if(strtolower($user_type) == 'member'){ 

                $_SESSION['user_type'] = 'member';  
                //header('Location: member-dashboard-home.php');
                header('Location: profile.php');

            }elseif(strtolower($user_type) == 'admin' || strtolower($user_type) == 'leader'){

                $_SESSION['user_type'] = strtolower($user_type);                                        
                //header('Location: admin-dashboard-home.php');
                header('Location: profile.php');
            }


        }else{
            $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Invalid login details!";
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);exit();
        }
    }
}

$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();

if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    header('Location: restricted.php');
    exit();
} else{
    echo "Login Failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();

}

$mysqli->close();

$_SESSION['main_title']  = "Login";
?>
```

Apology if my code is everywhere. Please if posible to edit my code or just explain what am during or wrong.

thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Hi as u can see have being working on this coding before I posted here... is not like am asking u create a project for me.

Comment: Well @chris85 did the first part, and now you want someone else to do the next part. Seems like you are kind of dependant on one of us writing most of it for you!

Comment: My suggestion: Indent your code sensibly, it makes it easier to read and more importantly **easier for you to debug**

Comment: I just reformatted your second piece of code and there looks to be some discrepancy in matching `{` and `}`

Comment: Just so you know, your code for checking whether a file exists, including it if it does, and ending script execution if it doesn't is *built into PHP*. Remove that whole block and just put in `require_once('include/connection.php')`. If the file is missing, PHP will show its own error message and will not continue further into the script.

Comment: Well am most say I agree with you guy's my code structure can be everywhere... apology. I will make it efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password' AND user_type = '$user_type'")))
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

But in prepared statements you need to use question marks in `prepare` instead of using concrete variable name.

So code could be like this:

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ? AND password = ? AND user_type = ?")))
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ")" . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Moreover you need to define variable `$user_type` before `bind_param`.

After `bind_param` you need to execute your query by `$stmt->execute();`

Further is necessary to bind every column from user table with variables when you use query like `SELECT *`

```
$stmt->bind_result($column_1, ..., $column_n);
```

In generally, look in more detail on the mysqli prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Lastly, I noticed you have some syntactic errors in your code. You have two more closing brackets there.

```
}else{
    $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Invalid login details!";
    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit();
}
}
}   <= Delete this bracket


else{
    echo "Login Failed: (" . $stmt->errno .")" . $stmt->error;
}
$stmt->close();

}   <= Delete this bracket
```

Comment: Oh yeah... great I will make note of that. Thanks.

Comment: If I amend the code how is the rest of the login code looking... I keep thinking I still to include or remove something.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... am looking in to this right now. Really appreciate ur input. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help:-)